# tabula.read_pdf - Error; })"): build_options() got an unexpected keyword argument 'spreadsheet'

Tags: python-3.x, tabula

I am scraping a PDF which runs perfectly on my computer (Windows). However when i try to execute the script from my remote-computer (Server-computer) i am not able to execute the script properly.

In my script i read the pdf as follow:

```
df_1 = tabula.read_pdf("fish.pdf", spreadsheet = True, area = (222.38,287.18,286.53,472.58), pandas_options={'header': None})
df_2 = tabula.read_pdf("fish.pdf", spreadsheet = True, area = (472.7,287.18,530.85,472.58),pandas_options={'header': None})
df_3 = tabula.read_pdf("fish.pdf", spreadsheet = True, area = (730.71,284.93,788.86,462.52),pandas_options={'header': None})
```

Then when i run the script on the remote-computer i get the following Error:

```
EXCEPTION IN (C:\PyScripts\rusfish.py, LINE 90 "df_1 = tabula.read_pdf("fish.pdf", spreadsheet = True, area = (222.38,287.18,286.53,472.58), pandas_options={'header': None})"): build_options() got an unexpected keyword argument 'spreadsheet'
```

Does anyone have a clue for why this error occurs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably have different versions on your server and your computer for tabula. The latest version doesn't have `spreadsheet` option. Depending on what you want to do, you can use other options like `lattice` or `stream`. https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html